Horror/Thriller Movie With Little Girl and Very Short Obese Middle Aged Woman
My girlfriend watched a live-action horror/thriller movie on television in the early 1990's and is trying to figure out the name of it. All she remembers is that there was a little girl around 8 to 10 years of age. She thinks the little girl's name was Cindy or Sydney or something phonetically similar to that. There was also a very short obese middle aged woman with a "high pitched scratchy voice" who took the little girl to a large dimly lit fog filled room. She believes the woman may have been imaginary, or possibly a ghost. She also seems to recall a multi-level garage at some point in the story-line.

I believe the name of the movie you are looking for is Poltergeist 3. The little girl's name was Carol Anne. 
Some weird facts about the movie is, the little girl who played Carol Anne (Heather O'Rourke) died shortly after the movie was released from some type of infection (IMDB says it was misdiagnosed Crohn's disease). Also, the scene in the garage you are talking about was done in live action. They didn't use special effects to create it. 

Wow! I never even thought about the old lady from Poltergeist. Nice work!

Were you referring to the parking garage scene with the snow & cars, or the one where Carol Anne went through the puddle?

Where she went through the puddle. I saw an interview with Tom Skerrit where he talked about it. It seemed more to me he was hyping the movie to get better attendance, but what he was really saying is the production was running on the cheap and couldn't afford to do it better.
